# Don't have manage in my Mobile Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to use the SQL query to delete contacts without channels. There doesn't appear to be a manage section where I can create the filtered list. It is a new configuration of MobileConnect, is there something I'm missing to enable this section? See attached:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to open a support case and they will resolve this issue, you can get there in around about way by clicking the down arrow on add contacts and choose 'Add manually' and then close out the pop up window

Comment: Thanks, I reached out to support. The workaround didn't work for me, but hopefully support can get the button enabled.